# Database tables: One-to-many of different types

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

Due to non-disclosure at my work, I have created an analogy of the situation. Please try to focus on the problem and not "Why don't you rename this table, m,erge those tables etc". Because the actual problem is much more complex.

Heres the deal,

Lets say I have a "Employee Pay Rise" record that has to be approved.

There is a table with single "Users".

There are tables that group Users together, forexample, "Managers", "Executives", "Payroll", "Finance". These groupings are different types with different properties.

When creating a "PayRise" record, the user who is creating the record also selects both a number of these groups (managers, executives etc) and/or single users who can 'approve' the pay rise.

What is the best way to relate a single "EmployeePayRise" record to 0 or more user records, and 0 or more of each of the groupings.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that the users are linked to the groups? If so in this case I would just link the employeePayRise record to one user that it applies to and the user that can approve. So basically you'd have two columns representing this. The EmployeePayRise.employeeId and EmployeePayRise.approvalById columns. If you need to get to groups, you'd join the EmployeePayRise.employeeId = Employee.id records. Keep it simple without over-complicating your design.

Comment: Don't know what to tell you then. Be more specific instead of "Due to non-disclosure at my work" if you want a better answer.

Comment: Better analogy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900793/database-design-one-to-many-of-different-types

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was to create a table that relates individual approvers to pay rise rows.

```
create table pay_rise_approvers (
  pay_rise_id integer not null references some_other_pay_rise_table (pay_rise_id),
  pay_rise_approver_id integer not null references users (user_id),
  primary key (pay_rise_id, pay_rise_approver_id)
);
```

You can't have good foreign keys that reference managers sometimes, and reference payroll some other times.  Users seems the logical target for the foreign key.

If the person creating the pay rise rows (not shown) chooses managers, then the user interface is responsible for inserting one row per manager into this table.  That part's easy.

A person that appears in more than one group might be a problem.  I can imagine a vice-president appearing in both "Executive" and "Finance" groups.  I don't think that's particularly hard to handle, but it does require some forethought.  Suppose the person who entered the data changed her mind, and decided to remove all the executives from the table. Should an executive who's also in finance be removed?

Another problem is that there's a pretty good chance that not every user should be allowed to approve a pay rise. I'd give some thought to that before implementing any solution.

Comment: Better analogy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900793/database-design-one-to-many-of-different-types

Answer (score 0):

I know it looks ugly but I think somethimes the solution can be to have the table_name in the table and a union query

```
create table approve_pay_rise (
  rise_proposal varchar2(10)     -- foreign key to payrise table
, approver varchar2(10)          -- key of record in table named in other_table
, other_table varchar2(15) );

insert into approve_pay_rise values ('prop000001', 'e0009999', 'USERS');
insert into approve_pay_rise values ('prop000001', 'm0002200', 'MANAGERS');
```

Then either in code a case statement, repeated statements for each other_table value (select ... where other_table = '' .. select ... where other_table = '') or a union select.

I have to admit I shudder when I encounter it and I'll now go wash my hands after typing a recomendation to do it, but it works.

Comment: Karl, Thanks for the suggestion - I had throught of this but I am trying to avoid putting logic in code if possible.

Comment: Better analogy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900793/database-design-one-to-many-of-different-types

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you'd might need two tables ("ApprovalUsers" and "ApprovalGroups"). The SELECT statement(s) would be a UNION of UserIds from the "ApprovalUsers" and the UserIDs from any other groups of users that are the "ApprovalGroups" related to the PayRiseId.

```
SELECT UserID
INTO   #TempApprovers
FROM   ApprovalUsers 
WHERE  PayRiseId = 12345

IF EXISTS (SELECT GroupName FROM ApprovalGroups WHERE GroupName = "Executives" and PayRiseId = 12345)
BEGIN
    SELECT UserID
    INTO   #TempApprovers
    FROM   Executives
END

....
```

EDIT: this would/could duplicate UserIds, so you would probably want to GROUP BY UserID  (i.e. SELECT UserID FROM #TempApprovers GROUP BY UserID)